# Android replace selected text in EditText with user input issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection, overwrite

I have a screen with prefilled EditText. Whole it's text is selected via

```
editText.setSelection(0, editText.getText().length());
```

I do that so users are able to rewrite that text immediately, but when I hit some key it doesn't write it. It just deletes the selected text and then allows me to write. Is this an expected behaviour please?

Comment: I'm not sure of what is your issue, but when you set an hint using `setHint()`, yes it is a normal behaviour that the text disapear.

Comment: Sry I should explain a little more. I use it as an input field for place suggestions from google. What I do is that I have a few predefined keywords (eg "Current location"). When you first get to screen with that EditText then it has prefilled keyword. And when user want to search for different location he should be able to type right away. But when it does it looks like the first letter that he typed was ignored, because when he hit keyboard for the first time it just cleared selected keyword, instead of replacing that selected keyword with pressed letter.

Comment: Meaning I can't user hint because it doesn't make sense in my scenario.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean exactly. Do you want the pre-filled text to disappear when the user clicks the edit text or not?

Comment: Yes. To be rewritten by what user pressed. Example: there is "Current location" in EditText and it is all selected. Now user presses A key and in EditText should be "A" (not selected and cursor after it).

Comment: I created a new project, added just one ordinary edittext with "Hello world" text, and used your command to select text. I run the project, the text in EditText is indeed selected, I press "a" , the selected text is gone and immediately "a" character appears. So I think there's something special in your situation for this behaviour (like some additional attributes in xml or some listeners in your code)

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setSelection(editText.length());
```

will set the cursor to the end but it is to be noted there are two types of text that are set.

There is a hint (this will be wiped as soon as you press on it and it just sits in the background as a prompt to the user)

```
 editText.setHint("Hey");
```

And then there is the text (this wont be wiped as soon as you press it)

```
 editText.setText("Hey");
```

Comment: Sry I should explain a little more. I use it as an input field for place suggestions from google. What I do is that I have a few predefined keywords (eg "Current location"). When you first get to screen with that EditText then it has prefilled keyword. And when user want to search for different location he should be able to type right away. But when it does it looks like the first letter that he typed was ignored, because when he hit keyboard for the first time it just cleared selected keyword, instead of replacing that selected keyword with pressed letter.

Comment: so you want it to clear, then if he presses 'c' for example, Current Location comes up?

Comment: Nope :) when he presses c, then just write c